# Tracing from an effect back to its cause in a large Python codebase

Tags: python, debugging

I have a reasonably large project in Django, which is a reasonably large framework, and I'm using a reasonably large number of apps, middlewares, context processors, etc. The scale means that when a part of the codebase runs for requests where I don't want it to, identifying why it did is hard. Straight code inspection is much too time-consuming, as is single-stepping through the entire request in a debugger.

In this particular case, my problem is that I'm getting "Vary: Cookie" set on every response, including some that I want heavily cached and where I shouldn't need any cookies. I suspect, but don't know how to prove, that some middleware or context processor is accessing `request.session` even when it doesn't use the result--though it might be an indirect access, such as through `request.user`. And of course it might be something else entirely.

In Python, how would you trace from an effect ("the Vary header was added to the response") back to its cause in a large codebase?

Comment: Hello. I'm not familiar with django, but if you need to find what has done `A['x'] = y` and `A` isn't a builtin object then you can just replace A.__setitem__ with your own that will check, whether "Vary: Cookie" header has appeared after executing `__setitem__`, and if so, just print call stack which will guide you to the thing that caused it. Another variant is to write a debugger that will execute your program line by line and check each time, if the header you need has been appended to particular object.

Comment: Thanks, @alex_jordan, that's a good start. How do you print the call stack programatically? And in this case I believe the header would be added if a flag is set elsewhere, so the call stack will tell me which flag triggered it; but can I trace field assignments to find when the flag was set? Finally, the objects in question are allocated per-request. Can I monkey-patch the class they come from to do this for all instances?

Comment: Jamey, the solution I provided below does just that and uses django error reporting so that you don't have to worry about the details of printing the stack trace yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a thought:  monkey patch the django HttpResponse class so that its `__setitem__` method raises an exception if the header being set is `Vary`.  You can take care of this from an otherwise do-nothing middleware when it's created.  It should give you a nice traceback from the line that's setting the header.

```
class MonkeyPatchMiddleware(object):

   def __init__(self):
       from django.http import HttpResponse

       original_set_item = HttpResponse.__setitem__

       def __setitem__(self, header, value):
           if header == "Vary":
               raise ValueError
           original_set_item(self, header, value)

       HttpResponse.__setitem__ = __setitem__
```

Install the middleware as the first thing in your middleware stack in your django settings file.

Comment: Thanks! I found it more convenient to try this in my app's `views.py` rather than adding a middleware. The traceback told me that it was `SessionMiddleware.process_response` that was calling `patch_vary_headers`, but then to find out why, I needed to discover what was setting `request.session.accessed`. Monkey-patching in `SessionBase.accessed = property(lambda self: False, raise_on_true)` got me a traceback with the true root cause.